# Problem passing IEnumerable<IDictionary> over WCF to Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, generics, datagrid

I have a WCF service which I am trying to use to generate an `IEnumerable<IDictionary>` and then build a grid on the fly from this.

The method signature on the server that returns the data is:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(GeneralServiceFault))]
IEnumerable<IDictionary> GetReport(string name, ReportingParameter[] parameters);
```

I'm building my service reference using:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Tools\slsvcutil.exe" http://localhost:8082/Service?wsdl /mergeConfig /config:..\ServiceReferences.ClientConfig /edb /namespace:"*,namespace.Service" /r:"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60129.0\System.Windows.dll"
```

This generates a service reference which boils down to:

```
 public Dictionary<object, object>[] EndGetReport(IAsyncResult result)
```

Is there anyway I can get this to generate with the generic IDictionary so I can call the extension method found [here](http://blog.bodurov.com/How-to-Bind-Silverlight-DataGrid-From-IEnumerable-of-IDictionary/)? Or if not how should I go about doing this?

Comment: And what types do you transport in your dictionary? WCF service doesn't know them so it doesn't expose them in metadata. Because of that the client expects only `Dictionary<object, object>`

Comment: the dictionary objects are populated by GetValue() using the DataReader class. This can return any of the clr types specified that the DataReader class can return. It doesn't return any of my own types. Do these need to be specifically set up as known types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible...
Just change that extension method to:

```
public static IEnumerable ToDataSource<TDictionary>(
          this IEnumerable<TDictionary> list) where TDictionary : IDictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using / have access to Visual Studio, then try this:

- Right-click the Service Reference for the service within Visual Studio Solution Explorer
- Select the option which reads 'Configure Service Reference'
- Make sure the Collection Type specified is `System.Collections.Generic.List`
- Make sure the Dictionary collection type specified is `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`

Apologies, but I'm not familiar with the command-line reference of `svcutil` for generating anything other than a default configuration.